# Recursion "maximum call stack size exceeded" - decimal to hexadecimal converter

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack

I'm trying to make a decimal to hexadecimal converter without using `Number.prototype.toString` (this is an assignment which does not allow that function).  I am attempting to use recursion to try to work it.  Everything works until the `else` inside the main `else` if that makes any sense.  It gives me that error when I run it for any number above 255 (i.e. any number which has more than 2 digits in hexadecimal).  Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
var number = parseInt(prompt("Give me a number and I will turn it into hexadecimal!"));
var digit = 1;
var hexConverter = function () {
    if (digit === 1) {
        if (Math.floor(number / 16) === 0) {
            console.log(hexDigits[number]);
        } else {
            digit = 16;
            console.log(hexConverter(), hexDigits[number % 16]);
        }
    } else {
        if (Math.floor(number / (digit * 16)) === 0) {
            return (hexDigits[Math.floor(number / digit)]);
        } else {
            return (hexConverter(), hexDigits[number % (digit * 16)]);
        }
        digit = digit * 16;
    }
};
hexConverter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing `digit` after making the recursive call, so it will be stuck at 16 and never get to the point where you increase it.

Move the `digit = digit*16;` to before the recursive call, just as you have `digit = 16` in the first part.

Comment: I moved it before the recursion part and changed the "digit * 16" in the return to just "digit". Now the recursion doesn't work. There's no error anymore but it displays only 2 of the digits. Can you help me?

Comment: @user2852803: You are using `return` instead of `console.log` in the second part of the code, so if you are looking for the result in the console, you won't see it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toHex(x) {
   var res='',h;
   while (x) {
     res=(((h=x&15)<10)? h : String.fromCharCode(55+h)) + res; 
     x>>=4;
   }
   return res;
}
```

Would work quite fine.
Question to you : why only 'quite' ? :-)